# Nested models: should we use criteria like adjusted R squared, AIC/BIC, Mallows' Cp or the F-test?

Tags: linear-model, model-selection

I am confused about which one to use for, say testing $ H_0: \beta_1 = \beta_2 $. The F-test for comparison of residual sum of squares can be used here, as can things like adjusted $R^2$, AIC/BIC or Mallows'
$C_p$. So which one should I use? Or is there some better method that I am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You did not state the purpose.  If you use any of these for model "selection" it can be a bad idea and the final standard errors will be invalidated.  Pre-specifying models is usually better.  But if you wanted to have a competition between two models the index you choose depends on the goal.

- $R^{2}_\text{adj}$ penalizes the likelihood ratio $\chi^2$ for the model by subtracting the number of predictors $p$, to get a nearly unbiased estimate of likely future performance in predicting new outcomes when the design matrix $X$ of predictors doesn't change.  The expected value of the model $\chi^2$ under the null hypothesis that there are no useful predictors is $p$, so $p$ is a "chance correction".  See [this](https://hbiostat.org/bib/r2.html) for more.  You can call $R^{2}_\text{adj}$ an "in-sample measure" penalized for overfitting.
- AIC penalizes the model $\chi^2$ by $2p$ to recognize that future applications of the model may also be subject to fluctuations in the design matrix $X$ - a penalty of one $p$ is for possibly overfitting predictors using the $X$ at hand, and an additional $p$ penalty makes AIC an "out-of-sample measure".

A related worthwhile exercise is to use the bootstrap or many repeats of 10-fold cross-validation to get an overfitting-corrected estimate of $R^2$ and to compare that to the original $R^{2}_\text{adj}$.